# How do you print only non-zero values in a table from MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, record

So, for example, I have this table from my MySQL with a certain record *a*:

```
 | col1 | col2 | col3 |
a|  0   |   1  |  2   |
```

I'd like to echo this record in PHP, but I'd not want that column with the zero value to be printed as well. So it would look like this.

```
 | col2 | col3 |
a|  1   |  2   |
```

The code

```
 $get = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('0', '1', '2')";
 $result = mysql_query($get);

 echo "<table><tr><td>col2</td><td>col3</td></tr>";

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo"<tr> <td>".$row['col2']." </td>
    <td>".$row['col3']."</td>
    </tr>";
}
```

This is the manual execution of the code, but if I had some tens of columns, I'd like the code to detect which columns have zeros, which I'm not familiar with.

Yeah, so basically, I have no idea of the syntax that allows me to loop through all the columns of a given table in MySQL. I'm working with MySQL in PHP

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: if($col1!=0) echo $col1; ?

Comment: Sorry, will add shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($result_array as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value!=NULL)
    printf("<td>%s</td>", $value);
}
```

Comment: Great answer sugest that "!= 0" is perhaps more pertinent to the OP, given an entry of '0' is not === null

Comment: This code is really great, though it requires me to transfer my data from my database at MySQL into PHP. Is it possible to sift through the columns directly from MySQL?

Comment: Yep, I used negation of is equal to. I advise you to read more about logical operations here, it's good for everything http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: Oh, crap. So my problem all boils down to the IS NOT NULL syntax. I'm so sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Yeah nice, np. You can vote up my answer, if I helped you (the triangle above the number on left side, next to the my code ;))